# Formatting output of objdump -sj .text filename.exe

Tags: linux, pe

I am hoping to get the contents of the .text section, of a Microsoft PE file using a linux command.  When I use

```
objdump -sj .text filename.exe
```

the output consists of the offset, in hexadecimal format, on the far left, followed by the content, in hexadecimal format, in the middle and a mixture of dots and ASCII characters on the right.  I don't know if the dots represent unprintable characters.

Is there a way to adjust the format of the output?  Ideally, I am hoping to get the printable strings without the hexadecimal numbers.  I have looked through the objdump man page but could not see a way to do this.

Comment: Hi @otagoharbour, this question would likely be better asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I tried posting it there but the only appropriate tag they had was linux and maybe hexdump.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor's answer is correct, but a bit short.

First, get the size and file offset of the .text segment using objdump -h:

```
$ objdump -h /path/to/Windows/System32/calc.exe
....
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00060cc9  0000000100001000  0000000100001000  00000600  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .rdata        00010ec4  0000000100062000  0000000100062000  00061400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

Now you know the text section starts at `0x600` and ends at `0x61400`.

Then, use `strings` and have it print the file offsets:

```
$ strings -a -t x -e l  /path/to/Windows/System32/calc.exe
  620e0 Edit
  62128 Button
  62138 SysDateTimePick32
  62160 ComboBox
  ...
```

In this particular file, as you see, there are no strings in the text segment; the first string (Edit) is already in the .rdata section. With most versions of `strings`, you don't need the `-a`, and you can select the character encoding with `-e`, 16 bit little endian in this case. See the manual page for other encodings.

You can use some of the Linux text utilities to further postprocess the output, but as @JasonGeffner said, superuser.com is a better place to ask about them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just printable strings from the binary, a better tool is the [`strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) command.

Comment: I don't think strings can specifically select the .text section from a PE file.  What would be ideal, as output, would be the individual bytes in extended ASCII format.  Thanks,